# simplifying a MySQL query, pulling table name dynamically from table data

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table and one of the fields is 'template'. This field will point to the correct template table to reference the unique fields for that particular template.

So for example if table.template = 'news', I also need to pull the info from the news_template table to have the complete set of listing info. Right now I only know how to do this with two separate query calls from PHP.

Is there anyway to do a join with a dynamic table name based on the data in one of the columns?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make a table name dynamic in a query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824727/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-table-name-dynamic-in-a-query)

Comment: aha! yes, you're right. Sounds like it can't be done. Sorry for the dupe. missed it in my pre post searches. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done directly in MySQL without splitting it into multiple queries.

I usually see this handled by querying for the info needed to determine the correct table name, then the scripting language being used (PHP?) puts together another query using that information.

Comment: yeah, that's my first thought for it, but I want to try and limit the number of queries I'm making to the server. Just wanted to check and make sure I'm not missing something out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would suggest restructuring your `*_template` tables into a new table called `template_data`. This table can then have a column called `template_name`. Then selecting the correct data becomes a simple SQL query, eg.

```
select Parameter, Value from template_data where template_name = ?
```

Comment: problem is with the complexity of the templates, I'll have some with 3 columns and some with 49 cols, all unique so it's going to be a huge table that way. won't that make the queries slower?